# Add whitespace as indentation with `indent-region`

Tags: indentation, region, whitespace

When using indent-region, emacs will indent code and leave bank spaces untouched. It seems to me that the majority prefer to delete whitespace. However I prefer white space indented with the code. An example is shown below.

```
void foo(){
    do_something();
--->
    do_something_else();
}
```

Let's say that the code is wrapped in an if block, then using indent-region the result is as follows.

```
void foo(){
    if(...){
        do_something();
--->
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

How would I edit my .emacs file to include the whitespace with the indentation? The result should be the following.

```
void foo(){
    if(...){
        do_something();
------->
        do_something_else();
    }
}
```

Also note that I have replaced the electric-indent-post-self-insert-function with one that does not delete whitespace.